# Pushing/nexting a value from an observable subject, isn't updating a subscribed observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs5

I've put together a simple example that I believe should work.. but it doesn't :(
I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'sandbox.template.html'
})
export class SandBoxPage implements OnInit {

    dataSubject: Subject<string> = Subject.create();
    data$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private platform: Platform) {
        this.data$ = this.dataSubject
            .asObservable()
            .startWith("First value in the observable");
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log("onClick()");
        this.dataSubject.next(Date.now + " value");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit()");
        this.data$.subscribe((v) => {
            console.log("new value", v);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Error", err);
        });
    }
}
```

I have a button hooked up to the `onClick()` but the console.log in my subscribe doesn't fire. It only fires once with the `startsWith` value at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a subject with `create`, you need to give it the `observer` and `observable` parameters according to the documentation.

> Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable)

Source: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable

Solution:
Just create it with new

```
dataSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @Matt We've all been there :)